# Need help in overcoming the incompatibility of a certain behat dependencies set with a PHP 5.3

Tags: php, bdd, behat

I was having a certain behat configuration with a specific dependencies set which worked well with PHP 5.5. But later I've had to transfer that configuration to a server with jenkins. The trouble is that server has PHP 5.3 installed with no possibility to be updated.

Despite dependencies refused to be installed via composer in a normal way, I've forced them to be installed anyway using the "--ignore-platform-reqs" parameter.

Having installed the dependencies, I've faced with another issue which I could not had overcome that easily. It simply displays an error while attempting to execute "bin/behat" command:

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php on line 77
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:0
PHP   2. includeIfExists() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:21
PHP   3. include() .../automated-tests/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:17
PHP   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit617eef80953ba1e8b93feeaeccb52bc0::getLoader() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/autoload.php:7
PHP   5. composerRequire617eef80953ba1e8b93feeaeccb52bc0() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:49
PHP   6. require() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:59
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php on line 77 Call Stack: 0.0006 645368 1. {main}() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:0 0.0008 645976 2. includeIfExists() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:21 0.0016 649328 3. include('.../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/autoload.php') .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:17 0.0021 680968 4. ComposerAutoloaderInit617eef80953ba1e8b93feeaeccb52bc0::getLoader() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/autoload.php:7 0.0082 1106296 5. composerRequire617eef80953ba1e8b93feeaeccb52bc0() .../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:49 0.0089 1109928 6. require('.../workspace/automated-tests/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php') .../automated-tests/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:59
```

Here's the list of dependencies in composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "behat/gherkin": "~4.4",
    "drupal/drupal-extension": "~3.1",
    "emuse/behat-html-formatter": "dev-master"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "bossa/phpspec2-expect": "~1.0",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~0.5",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.5",
    "jakoch/phantomjs-installer": "1.9.8"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Behat\\Behat":    "src/",
      "Behat\\Testwork": "src/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that PHP 5.3 is no longer supported; it went 'end-of-life' a few months ago. The minimum supported PHP version right now is 5.4. The problem you've got is due to PHP code with syntax that is only supported from 5.4 upward. You're likely to get this kind of problem more and more as devs use more recent PHP features. Your best solution would be to upgrade your PHP version, preferably jump all the way up to 5.6 (consider looking at 7.0 as well, but there are more compatibility issues with that than with 5.6)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. But we're strictly sticking with this PHP version as our client's server is running on that PHP version as well. I've tried to use my persuation skills and told the same about PHP versions...but had no luck with it.

Comment: I get so annoyed by clients like that. It's one thing not to want to upgrade to a new version immediately, but still not upgrading something when it's no longer supported is negligent. I bet they'll still be stuck on 5.3 in another five years time. Grrr. It's the same attitude that means there's still millions of Windows XP systems out there. And it's the same attitude that's constantly resulting in hacked servers and data leaks getting in the news. Some people just don't get the importance of keeping their software up-to-date. (heh. sorry for the rant...!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem. I've changed the "require" block  in composer.json to the following:

```
{
  "require": {
    "drupal/drupal-extension": "*",
    "emuse/behat-html-formatter": "dev-master"
  },
```

Notice that I've got rid of the ""behat/gherkin": "~4.4"" and changed drupal/extension version to "*". **Thus it downloads the latest and most stable version along with all dependencies it requires (so behat 4 is included as well) according to the specs of my system (so its PHP 5.3 compatible).**

At least that's the way I see it. Please, correct me If I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Short array syntax **[]** was added in PHP 5.4, so I guess you're running some older version of PHP on the shared server. Normally replacing **[]** with **array()** would help, but here it is an external vendor package so it's not advised to modify the code as changes would be overwritten when vendor package is updated. Other than that the only way to fix that issue is to use newer version of PHP.

[From this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367442/i-have-error-in-laravel-on-function-vendor-guzzlehttp-psr7-src-functions-php-on)

Comment: Yeah, it's 5.3, so the array[] declarations is not supported. I was thinking of replacing all [] with () but that is not an elegant solution with a risk of breaking things up (especially in places where this brackets are actually required).
Another solution I was thinking of is to downgrade the dependencies so the actual set is actually 5.3 compatible. But that's gonna take a long time to get the right combination of them so they are all compatible with both 5.3 and with each other.

Comment: You're talking about using [guzzle/guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle) instead of [guzzlehttp/guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle)? I think this is your only solution if you can't update to `php 5.5`

Comment: This is an idea actually. I'd give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried installing guzzle/guzzle 3.5.0 (by adding it into the require-dev section) and added it to the composer. But I've ended up with both guzzle and guzzlehttp instead for some reason, and so it was a no-go for me (or of course I might've done something in the wrong way though).